# Ruby task. Dictionary class failure. Dictionary finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I got stuck on the find method while doing Ruby exercises. My code does not pass one of the rspec requirements, and I do not really understand why.

Here is my code:

```
class Dictionary

attr_accessor :entries

def initialize
    @hash={}
end


def add(a)
    if a.class == Hash
        a.each_pair { |k, v|
            @hash[k]=v
        }
    else
       @hash[a]=nil 
    end
end


def entries
    @hash
end


def keywords
    @hash.keys
end


def include?(k)
    @hash.key?(k)
end


def find(str)
    result = {}
    if str.class == Hash
        str.each_pair { |k, v|
            if @hash.key?(k)==true
                result[k]=v
            else
                result
            end
        }
    elsif str.class == String 
        if @hash.key?(str)==true
            @hash.each_pair { |k, v|
                if k==str
                    result[k]=v
                else
                    result
                end
            }
        else @hash.include?(str)==true
            @hash.each_pair {|k, v|
                if v==str
                    result[k]=v
                else
                    result
                end
            }
        end
    end     
  end


end
```

Here is the spec that fails:

```
it "finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing" do
  @d.add("fiend")
  @d.add("great")
  expect(@d.find("nothing")).to be_empty
end
```

The terminal:
    finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing (FAILED - 1)

```
Failures:

1) Dictionary finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing
 Failure/Error: expect(@d.find("nothing")).to be_empty
   expected `{"fiend"=>nil, "great"=>nil}.empty?` to return true, got         false
 # ./spec/11_dictionary_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top   (required)>'
```

My find function returns an empty hash if I run it without rspec. Why does  rspec return true when checking whether the returned hash is empty? Is the spec requirement wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please format the question for readability. Code samples should be indented four spaces, with internal indentation using two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby every method returns the return value of the last executed command of given method. In case of your `find` method for string, the last method executed is `@hash.each_pair`, which always returns its target. You need to modify your method and return your `result` object at the end.

```
def find(str)
    result = {}
    if str.class == Hash
        str.each_pair { |k, v|
            if @hash.key?(k)==true
                result[k]=v
            else
                result
            end
        }
    elsif str.class == String 
        if @hash.key?(str)==true
            @hash.each_pair { |k, v|
                if k==str
                    result[k]=v
                else
                    result
                end
            }
        else @hash.include?(str)==true
            @hash.each_pair {|k, v|
                if v==str
                    result[k]=v
                else
                    result
                end
            }
        end
    end
    result    
end
```

That is the minimum to make it work. Now per your code - there is so much to improve it falls far from the scope of this website. Please post this to CodeReview community.

Comment: This is what I've just done. And it works. Thank you!

Comment: Both of you, please note that [codereview.se] only takes code that is **already working as the author intended**.

Comment: @Zak - this is why i answered the question first. :)

Comment: @user3907934 - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Like StackOverflow, but with more concern on code quality/readability/improvement than bug fixing.